# SWUP JS external function call

Tags: javascript, gsap, jsobject, swup

this is my first time using swup js with the js plugin. https://swup.js.org/plugins/js-plugin

I can see that the trigger to go to the clicked page lies inside the object array of options.

My question is there anyway I can trigger the "next" from external function

```
const options = [
  {
    from: '(.*)',
    to: '(.*)',
    in: function(next) {
      document.querySelector('#swup').style.opacity = 0;
      TweenLite.to(document.querySelector('#swup'), 0.5, {
        opacity: 1,
        onComplete: next
      });
    },
    out: (next) => {
      document.querySelector('#swup').style.opacity = 1;
      TweenLite.to(document.querySelector('#swup'), 0.5, {
        opacity: 0,
        onComplete: next
      });
    }
  }
];

const swup = new Swup({
  plugins: [new SwupJsPlugin(options)]
});
```

how do I trigger the "next " from another outside function not within Const options?

for example

```
counts trigger = function(){
 
 options.next();

thanks
```

this doesn't work

thanks

Comment: i think your second code sample is broken. Can you please fix that?

Comment: We at GreenSock recommend that you use [GSAP 3 formatting](http://greensock.com/3).

Comment: Hi Thanks guys,
So basically i just want to call the "next" function within the GSAP onComplete event that nested inside the const options from the outside. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Swup JS plugin uses the defined options to run `in` and `out` functions at the right time while passing the `next` argument to it.

The `next` argument is present only as a way to let swup know that the animation has finished and it can continue in whatever it needs to do next.